# Default option in select is not working using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, browser

I am following an AngularJS tutorial, and I wanted to validate my form. I decided to add a default option to the `select` element.

However, even after adding `selected=""`, the browser won't show it as default.

I have tried this without AngularJS and it works fine, so I'm guessing the script is blocking something.

How can I define a default option for my `select` element?

**PS**: I'm using Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 m

```js
var controllers = angular.module('formsApp.Controllers', []);
controllers.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todoList = [{
    action: 'Get groceries',
    complete: false
  }, {
    action: 'Call plumber',
    complete: false
  }, {
    action: 'Buy running shoes',
    complete: true
  }, {
    action: 'Buy flowers',
    complete: false
  }, {
    action: 'Call family',
    complete: false
  }];
  $scope.addNewItem = function(newItem) {
    $scope.todoList.push({
      action: newItem.action + ' (' + newItem.location + ')',
      complete: false
    });
  };
});

var app = angular.module('formsApp', ['formsApp.Controllers']);
```

```css
form input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="formsApp">

<head>
  <title>Forms</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="todoPanel" class="panel" data-ng-controller="todoCtrl">
    <h3 class="panel-header">
          To Do List
          <span class="label label-info">
           {{(todoList | filter: {complete: false}).length }}
          </span>
         </h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="well">
          <form name="todoForm" novalidate data-ng-submit="addNewItem(newTodo)">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="actionText">Action:</label>
              <input type="text" id="actionText" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newTodo.action" required="" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="actionLocation">Location:</label>
              <select id="actionLocation" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newTodo.location" required="">
                <option selected="">Home</option>
                <option>Office</option>
                <option>Mall</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-ng-disabled="todoForm.$invalid">
              Add
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in todoList">
              <td>
                {{$index + 1}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.action}}
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.complete" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the model is not defined (newTodo.location) so AngularJS doesn't know which option to select. Moreover your options don't have a value, so I'm not sure how you want to populate the model

Comment: But the `selected` attribute should have nothing to do with AngularJS, right? I mean it's something from HTML5, it should not have to inspect my AngularJS scope at all

Comment: @Sphaso What do you mean by the options not having a value? I'm a beginner on this topic, but aren't `Home`, `Office` and `Mall` the options values?

Comment: try ng-selected: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: As to "selected" not having to do with AngularJS: yes and no, the issue is that you're binding to an ng-model, so Angular selects the option corresponding to the model, which as far as I can tell is none, because the model is empty

Comment: As to values, I didn't know that if you have no 'value' attribute it takes the text inside. The things you learn on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Thank you both for the support and information! :). I managed to make it work using @StaffordWilliams 's suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dev guide for [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected);

> The HTML specification does not require browsers to preserve the
>   values of boolean attributes such as selected. (Their presence means
>   true and their absence means false.) If we put an Angular
>   interpolation expression into such an attribute then the binding
>   information would be lost when the browser removes the attribute. The
>   ngSelected directive solves this problem for the selected attribute.
>   This complementary directive is not removed by the browser and so
>   provides a permanent reliable place to store the binding information.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add another property and reference it from there:

```
{
    action: 'Call family',
    complete: false,
    selected: 'selected'
  }];

{
    action: 'Call family',
    complete: false,
    selected: ''

  }];
```

Comment: Is this right? Should the controller be aware of which item is selected? Isn't that a responsability of the view?

Comment: I think it all depends on the approach. If it's a static decision or even if it's decided dynamically I don't see problem in using it as a variable to make decisions. Not really any different than using a variable name in a searching/filtering technique.